# How to add 2 volume sliders to my mp3 players in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, audio, slider, volume

Easy people. Im currently trying to add 2 volume sliders to my existing project. I have two turntables, deck1 & deck2 but i need to be able to control the volume of each deck individually.

Im relatively new to actionscript 3 so im struggling abit. Can anyone help me please, here is my code..

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.text.TextField;

//variables
var mySound:Sound;
var myChannel:SoundChannel;
var nowPlaying:Boolean = false;
var nowPaused:Boolean = false;
var p:uint = 0;
var songfile:String;
var songtitle:String;

deck1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, deck1_data);
deck2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, deck2_data);
//song3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, song3_data);
stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);
stop2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);

pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseSound);

function deck1_data(myEvent:MouseEvent):void {
songfile = "audio/desire.mp3";
songtitle = "Skeptical - Desire";
playSound(null);
    }
    function deck2_data(myEvent:MouseEvent):void {
songfile = "audio/tundra.mp3";
songtitle = "Skeptical - Tundra";
playSound(null);
    }
    //function song3_data(myEvent:MouseEvent):void {
songfile = "audio/always_be_mine.mp3";
songtitle = "Skeptical - Always Be Mine";
playSound(null);

    function stopSound(myEvent:MouseEvent):void {
if (nowPlaying) {
myChannel.stop();
p = 0;
nowPlaying = false;
nowPaused = false;
  }
    }


    function playSound(myEvent:Event):void {
    mySound = new Sound;
    mySound.load(new URLRequest(songfile));
    title_txt.text = songtitle;
if (isPlaying) {
    myChannel.stop();
    myChannel = mySound.play(0);
} else {
    myChannel = mySound.play(0);
    nowPlaying = true;
     }
    }

    function pauseSound(myEvent:MouseEvent):void {
if (isPlaying) {
    p = Math.floor(myChannel.position);
    myChannel.stop();
    nowPlaying = false;
    nowPaused = true;
} else if (nowPaused) {
    myChannel = mySound.play(p);
    nowPlaying = true;
    nowPaused = false;
}
    }

    title_txt.text = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

For controlling volume you will need `SoundTransform`. Create sliders, and store volumes as numbers. And when you start deck sound, apply `soundTransform` with deck volume value:

```
myChannel = mySound.play(0, 0, new SoundTransform(myDeck1Volume));
//or
//myChannel = mySound.play(0, 0, new SoundTransform(myDeck2Volume));
```

As for sliders. You could use [Slider component](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa1.html)

Comment: Ok, i have tried this but it im not too sure where i am going wrong. Would i place that bit of code here: function playSound(myEvent:Event):void {
mySound = new Sound;
mySound.load(new URLRequest(songfile));
title_txt.text = songtitle;
 if (isPlaying) {
  myChannel.stop();
myChannel = mySound.play(0, 1, new SoundTransform(myDeck1Volume));
 } else {
  myChannel = mySound.play(0);
  nowPlaying = true;
 }
}

Comment: Every call to Sound.play, should be with SoundTransform